# SQL: Remove duplicates in pair query

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have this query :

```
SELECT a.`name` "n1", b.`name` "n2"
    FROM    `Table` a, `Table` b
    WHERE   a.`nb` = b.`nb`
            AND a.`name` != b.`name`
```

It almost works as I want, I get this result :

```
---------------------------------
| n1            | n2            |
|--------------------------------
| aa            | bb            |
| bb            | aa            |
---------------------------------
```

I think you get the issue: i'd like no to have the duplicates I get reversed in this query. Is there a way?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Yes i missed that : Mysql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can arbitrarily decide that you always display the "smaller" string as `n1` by using the `<` operator instead of the `!=` operator in order to avoid this type of "swapped" pairs:

```
SELECT a.`name` "n1", b.`name` "n2"
FROM   `Table` a, `Table` b
WHERE  a.`nb` = b.`nb` AND a.`name` < b.`name`
```

Comment: Im struggling to understand how your answer works, perhaps you could go through it?

Comment: @user2662639 I thought I did - can you narrow down your question a bit? What would you like me to elaborate?